# C - What happen to old data when char pointer set to new address?

Tags: c, pointers, char

Let's say we have a simple char*, then we re-assign the address.

```
char* foo = "Hello"; // [Hello] is somewhere in the memory.
char* bar = "World"; // [World] is somewhere in the memory.
foo = bar; // 'foo' and 'bar' pointing to "World", What happen to "Hello"?
```

I know "*Hello*" and "*World*" are static, but did the smart compilers understand that and clean memory for you?

**-- Edit & Info --**

Based on the comments, it's seem the result is different based on two things, the code, and the compiler optimization flag.

```
// Example 1
// Compiler Optimization Off
char* foo = "Hello";
char* bar = "World";
foo = bar; // <-- "Hello" Still on the memory.

// Example 2
// Compiler Optimization On
char* foo = "Hello"; // <-- "Hello" never exist on binary.
char* bar = "World";
foo = bar;

// Example 3
// Compiler Optimization Off
char* foo = "Hello"; // Exist on binary because it's used on the next line
printf("%s\n", foo);
char* bar = "World";
foo = bar; // Probably "hello" still exist on memory because optimization is off.

// Example 4
// Compiler Optimization On
char* foo = "Hello"; // Exist on binary because it's used on the next line
printf("%s\n", foo);
char* bar = "World";
foo = bar; // <-- What happen to "Hello" now?
```

Can you please **explain Example 4**?

Thank you.

Comment: It won't "clean", it might simply eliminate it from the final binary if it sees the literal `"Hello"` is not used anywhere.

Comment: If you never use `foo` between the assignments, a smart compiler should notice that and optimize away the `Hello` string.

Comment: You can use `strings a.out | grep Hello` to see if the string is in the binary.

Comment: In general, if you overwrite the only pointer then the memory is lost until the end of the program.  This means it is allocated but not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the result using the godbolt.org compiler explorer with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    char* foo = "Hello"; // [Hello] is somewhere in the memory.
    char* bar = "World"; // [World] is somewhere in the memory.
    foo = bar; // 'foo' and 'bar' pointing to "World", What happen to "Hello"?
    printf("%s\n", foo);
}
```

With no optimization, both strings are in the binary.

https://godbolt.org/z/77xbxbGG4

With `-O3` optimization, `Hello` is not put in the binary.

https://godbolt.org/z/soeqjYGKo

Note that this optimization is only possible because the initial value of `foo` is never actually used. This is a pretty unrealistic example -- why would you initialize `foo` if you're going to immediately reassign it?

Comment: You are right, I added your explanation on Example 2, I got it now, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens to the old data. In fact, the specifications say that nothing should happen. `"Hello"` lasts for the duration of the program, even if `foo` no longer points to it.

Comment: If you can't reference it, a compiler can remove it, since there's no way to tell the difference.

Comment: This is only a part of an answer. In the snippet posted by the OP it might be even not true for an optimizing compiler.

Comment: @Barmar: True, that's the "as-if" rule. But real compilers don't bother. The complexity of figuring that out is not worth the small saving. And for larger strings, the OS will just swap out the memory as needed.

Comment: @msalters I guess it's fine on a PC, but this is an issue on IoT devices that have very limited memory, I was thought optimization compile flag will clean it.

Comment: @MSalters I just tested it on a Mac. `World` is in the binary, `Hello` isn't.

Comment: @ShellX3: On IoT devices, the string might well be in ROM (and therefore you really should write `const char*`).

Comment: @ShellX3 If there are memory concerns, the *programmer* should be taking them in account and use his knowledge of C and compiler works to optimize the code or write it in a way he knows is optimizable by the compiler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Of course, in a real program you wouldn't initialize to a string if the value is never actually used (an exception I can think of is old-style RCSid strings).

Comment: @EugeneSh. But it could also occur due to automated code generation, macros, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Hello" and "World" are string literals that have static storage duration. That is when they appeared in the program the compiler stores them as character arrays.

So after these declarations

```
char* foo = "Hello";
char* bar = "World";
```

the pointers foo and bar point to first characters of these character arrays.

After this assignment

```
foo = bar;
```

the string literal "Hello" is still alive but you have not an access to it.

You could write after this assignment for example the following

```
foo = "Hello";
```

Now depending on the compiler options the compiler either will assign the address of the first character of the previously used string literal or it can create one more array with static storage duration that will contain the same string "Hello".

That is this if statement

```
if ( "Hello" == "Hello" )
```

can be evaluated either to logical true or false depending on compiler options that specify whether identical string literals are stored as one character array or as two different character arrays.

Usually compilers collect string literals in a special memory extent named literal pool.